# What is gmail's restriction on sending mails if the recipient emails are broken?

Tags: gmail, email, google-account

I have an application that tries to send emails to our registered user base, but the problem is a large number of user's emails are not verified and are expected to be non-existent or broken. So is there a limit which says that beyond this many mail bounces the account is locked(or something similar). If yes what is the set of restrictions imposed like on number of different messages, or different emails, unique emails etc?

I know the restrictions exist but couldn't find the numbers.